# add axios authorization on nuxt config

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

How to add a global authorization header on nuxt.config.js?

tried

```
  axios: {
    defaults : {
      headers : {
        common: [
          {
            'Authorization' : '5fb9c42ceba425fb9c42ceba43'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

but not working

I can do

```
this.$axios.setHeader('Authorization', this.$store.state.appstore.akey);
```

but I find it not ideal when having multiple axios request because I have to add it on every request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, taken from the [module docs](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#headers).

```
axios: {
  headers : {
    common: {
      'Authorization' : '5fb9c42ceba425fb9c42ceba43'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created an plugin for it. Goto `plugins` and create `axios.js`:

```
export default function ({ $axios, store }) {
  if (process.client) {
    $axios.setToken(store.state.appstore.akey, 'Bearer')
  }
}
```

Then register your plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/axios'],
```